# Custom UIButton in Tab Bar not able to be hidden

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have went through many of Stacksoverflow question before asking. None was able to solve my issue. I made a custom button using

```
class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController {

let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "assetIcon"), for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .blue
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 35

    self.view.insertSubview(button, aboveSubview: self.tabBar)
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    let distance =  ((self.view.bounds.height)/100)*11

    // safe place to set the frame of button manually
    button.frame = CGRect.init(x: self.tabBar.center.x - 32, y: self.view.bounds.height - distance, width: 70, height: 70)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func hideTabButton() {
    self.button.isHidden = true
}

func showTabButton() {
    self.button.isHidden = false
   }
}
```

However, when i called the function of hideTabButton from another view where I want to hide it, the button still shows up.. I called the function from

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarVC") as! TabBarViewController
    vc.hideTabButton()
}
```

It didnt hide the button. Anyone with a solution or guide that can be of help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to hide it before it is created you just instantiated `TabBarViewController` right now you should just pass a flag from current screen to `TabBarViewController` screen and then in `TabBarViewController` screen
Do following.

```
class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController {
var hideButton:Bool = false
let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "assetIcon"), for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .blue
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 35
    self.view.insertSubview(button, aboveSubview: self.tabBar)
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    let distance =  ((self.view.bounds.height)/100)*11

    // safe place to set the frame of button manually
    button.frame = CGRect.init(x: self.tabBar.center.x - 32, y: self.view.bounds.height - distance, width: 70, height: 70)
    button.isHidden = hideButton
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func hideTabButton() {
    self.button.isHidden = true
}

func showTabButton() {
    self.button.isHidden = false
   }
}
```

Now just pass boolean value to `TabbarViewController` if  not instantiated already

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarVC") as! TabBarViewController
  vc.hideButton=true
}
```

If your tabbar is already instantiated Not instatiate it again just access it like below

```
if let tabController = self.tabbarController as? TabbarViewController{ tabController.button.isHidden = true }
```

And When trying unhide it back just change true to false

```
if let tabController = self.tabbarController as? TabbarViewController{ tabController.button.isHidden = false }
```

Comment: meaning add var hideButton:Bool = false
and vc.hideButton=true
correct? i tried it but it didnt work

Comment: i also added button.isHidden = hideButton at viewdidlayout..didnt work

Comment: have you placed a breakpoint at viewDidLayoutSubviews in tabbarController.

Comment: if yes do control reaching there?

Comment: and tell one more thing viewDidAppear is in tabbar controller or in some other class?

Comment: yes it reached there..weirdly, it is not being set to true

Comment: viewDidAppear is on the new View that i wanted to hide

Comment: I have already put breakpoint, the vc.button.isHidden = true..however it is there, not hidden

Comment: in That case  your approach to hide button is not valid

Comment: you are instantiating new object of tabbrController to hide button in old tabbarController object 
you just need to access tabbar old object not instantiate new one

Comment: for the time being instantiate do put  below  let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom) line out of any class and in viewDidAppear do  like below button.isHidden=true and tell me result

Comment: when i used ( let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarVC") as! TabBarViewController
    vc.hideTabButton() ) , i thought I am using the old tabBarController object?

Comment: no doing this, instantiates a newObject of tabbrConroller

Comment: i think i understand what u mean..But how should i make a new object without using UIButton(init:type: .custom)? I think u mean, everytime i come back here, although i hide it, it is being created again

Comment: no i mean right now you are not able to access ol object you should access old one instantiating new object not impacting on anything accept memory, But it does not allow to hide old one 
try like (self.tabbarController as! TabbarViewController).button.isHidden = true 
in your viewDidAppear.

Comment: with exception handling 
if let tabContoller = self.tabbarController as? TabbarViewController{
    tabController.button.isHidden = true
}

Comment: updating my answer according to your scenario too.

Comment: please do let us know too if we want it to appear back when i press back, how should we write. May help others too

Comment: sure just change true to false ;)